# CoqIDE 8.5 default font

Tags: fonts, version, coqide

Sorry for this trivial question --- What is CoqIDE's default font in Coq 8.5? Trying out Coq 8.6 w/ `nix-shell -p coq_8_6 --run coqide` changed my old CoqIDE font (and keybindings); I want them back but don't remember the font name. The exact version (not sure if this matters) is 8.5pl1. Sadly, a reboot and even `nix-env --rollback` didn't restore the settings (my 8.5 was installed w/ `nix` and `nix-shell -p coq_8_6 --run coqide` shouldn't install anything AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that CoqIDE settings are shared between versions, which has many drawbacks.
Likely, CoqIDE 8.6 has overwritten these settings and its install status doesn't matter.

Since what you are trying to do is to get back the default settings of CoqIDE 8.5, you can just remove the files in `~/.config/coq` or `~/.coq` and relaunch CoqIDE 8.5 (unless you had tweaked other parameters, in which case it would be a good idea to save them elsewhere). It should recreate them.

If you feel like, you could also explain your issue at https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/. I think it would be worth addressing.

PS: but as far as I can tell, the default font hasn't changed between 8.5 and 8.6... Last time it was mentioned changing was between 8.1 and 8.2 (move to Monospace font).

Comment: Thanks, backing up and restoring `~/.config/coq` seems to be a workaround for this problem. PS. I cannot edit your answer but suggest you replace "a monospace" w/ "Monospace"

Comment: Strangely, font name and attributes are the same but the appearance has [completely changed](https://ibb.co/m1nGNa) from 8.5 to 8.6

Comment: @jaam I can't see this difference on my own machine. It might be system-related. Did you try to compare the two versions provided by Nix? (Using `nix-shell -p coq_8_5 --run coqide` to get the older one.) Note that I'm on NixOS but the fonts I get look closer to your 8.5 version.

Comment: `nix-shell -p coq_8_5 --run coqide` gives me the same font that 8.6. So Nix installations seem to change the font's appearance (from that of Synaptics, w/ which 8.5pl1 was installed)

Comment: Correction: 8.5pl1 was installed w/ Nix, too. So the font's appearance changes between 8.5pl1 and 8.5pl3

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, CoqIDE >= 8.5pl3 overrides the system's default Monospace font<sup>1</sup>, while CoqIDE <= 8.5pl1 uses the default. The first step is to find the system's default:

```
fc-match monospace
```

> DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"

The second step is to change the font (under Edit > Preferences) to whatever `fc-match monospace` gave you.

<sup>1</sup> Possibly w/ FreeMono

Comment: That's interesting but I was again unable to reproduce it. Still, feel free to open a bug report.